# How do i have a default property in ItemView or Layout in Backbone.marionette.js

Tags: javascript, marionette, backbone-views

How do i have some default property in ItemView or Layout in Backbont.Marionette.js.

we have  the default property in model like the following .

```
Backbone.Model.extend({
       defaults: {
            contract:"",

        }
    });
```

in the above model we have `defaults` to have some default properties. Can we have something similar in `ItemView or Layout`

One should be able to change the value for the defaults which are specified in Itemview or Layout

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create defaults by specifying them in the view classes that you make. For example;

```
var MyView = Backbone.Marionette.Composite.extend({
    defaults:{
        something: "value"
    }
});
```

Now all instances of MyView will have these defaults

```
var view = new MyView({
    initialize: function(){
        var x = this.defaults.something; //x = "value"
    }
);
```